# Unable to query ContentResolver to get downloaded file's name from my_downloads but works fine in all_downloads

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

My app is set up to activate once a file with extension *.myappdata* is opened.  It accomplishes this through this intent-filter:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.ExamineFileActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\.myappdata" android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:scheme="content" android:pathPattern=".*\\.myappdata" android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I open a Chrome web browser (on a Nexus 7 running Android 6.0.1) and go to a website that downloads a file named "file123.myappdata" and click the Open link within Chrome.

That action triggers my app to open and this code to run, which will get the filename that was downloaded:

```
    Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

when this code runs (after I open the file from Chrome) the uri is *content://downloads/**my_downloads**/1602* and *cursor.moveToFirst()* returns **false**

Then I exit my app and go to the Downloads app and open the exact same file.  That triggers my app to open, the same code to run except with uri *content://downloads/**all_downloads**/1602* (everything else in the uri is exactly the same), the *cursor.moveToFirst()* call returns **true** and the cursor.getString() method returns "file123.myappdata" (which is exactly what I want).

Why is the cursor.moveToFirst() method not finding any data when I open the downloaded file from Chrome (giving me "my_downloads" in the uri) versus opening the same downloaded file from Downloads (giving me "all_downloads" in the uri)?

Comment: what does `ContentResolver#getType(Uri url)` return for both uri?

Comment: @pskink ContentResolver#getType(Uri url) returns "text/xml" in both cases.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? Encountered the exact same issue and couldn't find a workaround.

Comment: @TigerHix Did you get the fix for this issue?

Comment: @SKK No I didn't. :(