# ACTION_GET_CONTENT Picking Document from Downloads returns null

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on PDF pick and upload to server. Below code crashed when file picked from Downloads. And works fine if file choose from any other directory.

I have tried below code on oneplus 6, and nokia 6.1 which have (android 9)Pie OS.

In brief code, 
Intent Activity start:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file"), 2);
```

In `onActivityResult`

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
   boolean isError = false;
   Uri selectedURI = data.getData();
   String docPath = getPath(selectedURI);
....
}
```

Here is whole code `getPath(Uri uri)`

```
private String getPath(final Uri uri) {
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        if(isKitKat) {
            return getForApi19(uri);
        } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(uri, null, null);
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @TargetApi(19)
    private String getForApi19(Uri uri) {
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(this.getActivity(), uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                if (docId.startsWith("raw:")) {
                    return docId.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                }
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                    return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                }
                String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                        "content://downloads/my_downloads",
                        "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                        "content://downloads/all_downloads"
                };

                for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                    Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));
                    try {
                        String path = getDataColumn(contentUri, null, null);
                        if (path != null) {
                            return path;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                if (docId.startsWith("raw:")) {
                    return docId.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                }
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public String getDataColumn(Uri uri, String selection,
                                String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};

        try {
            cursor = this.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```

Only `content://downloads/my_downloads` return `Curser` Object. other `content://downloads/public_downloads` and `content://downloads/all_downloads` return `null`.

**Problem**:

When file selected from `Downloads` the `Cursor.moveToFirst()` is false. and I don't get file path.

Comment: Duplicate but not answered yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483196/unable-to-query-contentresolver-to-get-downloaded-files-name-from-my-downloads?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used use below code for

```
if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                String fileName = getFilePath(context, uri);
                if (fileName != null) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
                }

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
```

And getFilePath()

```
public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

refer: [This link](https://gist.github.com/HBiSoft/15899990b8cd0723c3a894c1636550a8)